# How te resize file image without change the pixels/resolution on php?

Tags: php

I have `ImageManipulation.php`  and want to re-size an image with it. when re-size it, it still change the resolution, if I upload image 2100 x 900 with 2,3MB filesize, on the server will save 700 x 600 80KB filesize.
How to save with same resolution but less filesize ?
ex : 2100x900 100KB file.

Here my imagecompression funtion :

```
function imageCompression($imgfile="",$thumbsize=0,$savePath=NULL, $compressRatio=100) {
    //echo 'Lets Compression Only';
    if($savePath==NULL) {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    }
    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($imgfile);
    /* The width and the height of the image also the getimagesize retrieve other information as well   */
    $imgratio=$width/$height; 

    //if($imgratio>1) {
        $newwidth=$thumbsize;
        $newheight=$thumbsize/$imgratio;
    //} else {
    //  $newheight=$thumbsize;       
    //  $newwidth=$thumbsize*$imgratio;
    //}

    $thumb=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight); // Making a new true color image
    $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($imgfile); // Now it will create a new image from the source
    imagecopyresampled($thumb,$source,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);  // Copy and resize the image
    imagejpeg($thumb,$savePath,$compressRatio); //100 --> Compression Ration Quality

    imagedestroy($thumb);
}
```

Comment: *"but less filesize ? ex : 2100x900 100KB file."* - Are you sure you want to do that? You're going to end up with a pretty bad looking file and you won't be able to bring it back to its original, unless you keep a copy of the original.

Comment: that is just example, my main idea is compress file size of the image. now, i can compress the image but still change image resolution.

Comment: did answer given work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the code given,

```
<?php 
function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

    return $destination;
}

$source_img = 'source.jpg';
$destination_img = 'destination .jpg';

$d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
```

?>

It should do your work.

Please change the source and destination, it will keep the same resolution.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do that is to convert the image web format using adobe Photoshop or any other tool. alternatively change the image to a .png file type 
it generally handles compression more gracefully.